# How to make replacements in Eclipse for multiple class files where number of lines are more than 25?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to perform  find and replacements for more than 200 class files,
where the number of lines to be replaced is more than 25 per class.
For instance:

```java
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
```

The Find and Replace option didn't help for a larger chunk of code.

Example block that to be replaced:

```java
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {


            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {

        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();

    }

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
```

This is an example, where there are multiple replacements are required

Comment: Please include an example of the lines you need to replace?

Comment: For instance , 


 -@Override
 -@DataProvider(parallel = true)
 public Object[][] scenarios() {
  return super.scenarios();
 }

 -@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
 public void setUpClass() throws Exception {

  testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

 }

 -@Override
 @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
 public void tearDownClass() {

  testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
 }

Comment: sorry for the bad formmating

Comment: How about what you want to replace to?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to replace, but a few hint : \s match any whitespace, \Q and \E "escape" a whole pattern sequence: to match `public Object[][] scenarios()`, you could use `public\s+\QObject[][]\E\s+\Qscenarios()\E`. Then again, there might be Eclipse plugins which does a better job. One that would work using an AST and ignoring some tokens (eg: spaces, comments, ...). I'm not an expert in IntelliJ, but I think it had a feature like that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your given pattern is same across all files (same spacing),

1. Highlight the code to be replaced.
2. Click *Search -> File -> File Search Tab*(make sure *Regular Expression* is checked), eclipse will convert your pattern to regex in 1 line, copy the expression some where for later use.
   [image: Step 2 screen capture]
3. Then repeat the same step for the code to search.
4. Click <kbd>Replace</kbd>, put the text from step 2 to *With*, check *Regular Expression* then click <kbd>Ok</kbd>